# Invertir una lista

Tags: c++, lista

no sé porque no me da `;n;` agradecería si alguien me ayuda a encontrar una respuesta a mi problema

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

    struct nodo{
        int nro;
        struct nodo*sgte;
    };

    typedef struct nodo *Tlista;

    void InsertFirst(Tlista&lista,int valor) {
        Tlista q;
        q = new(struct nodo);
        q->nro = valor;
        q->sgte = lista;
        lista = q;
    }
    void InsertEnd(Tlista&lista,int valor) {
        Tlista t,q = new(struct nodo);
        q->nro = valor;
        q->sgte = NULL;
        if(lista == NULL) {
            lista = q;
        } else {
            t = lista;
            while(t->sgte != NULL) {
                t = t->sgte;
            }
            t->sgte = q;
        }
    }
    void ShowList(Tlista lista) {
        int i = 0;
        while(lista != NULL) {
            cout<<i+1<<")"<<lista->nro<<endl;
            lista = lista->sgte;
            i++;
        }
    }
    int Greater(Tlista lista){
        int mayor = -99999999;
        while(lista != NULL){
            if(lista->nro > mayor){
                mayor = lista->nro;
            }
            lista = lista->sgte;
        }
        return mayor;
    }
    int Lower(Tlista lista){
        int menor = 99999999;
        while(lista != NULL){
            if(lista->nro < menor){
                menor = lista->nro;
            }
            lista = lista->sgte;
        }
        return menor;
    }
    void reverse(Tlista &lista){//Aquí está el problema
       Tlista ptr = lista;

      if(lista->sgte!=0)
      {
        ptr = reverse(lista->sgte);

        (lista->sgte)->sgte=list;
        lista->sgte=0;
      }

      return ptr;
    }
    int main(){
        Tlista lista = NULL;
        int op;
        int _dato;
        int pos;
        do{
            cout<<"\n\n1. Insertar al inicio\n2. Insertar al final\n3. Mostrar lista\n4. Dar mayor\n5. Dar menor\n6. Imprimir Invertida\n7. Salir\n>"; cin>>op;
            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    cout<<"\n\tNumero a insertar: "; cin>>_dato;
                    InsertFirst(lista,_dato);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout<<"\n\tNumero a insertar: "; cin>>_dato;
                    InsertEnd(lista,_dato);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout<<"\nMostrando lista\n";
                    ShowList(lista);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout<<"\n\tEl mayor es: "<<Greater(lista);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cout<<"\n\tEl menor es: "<<Lower(lista);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    cout<<"\nMostrando lista\n";

                    ShowList(reverse(lista));
                    break;
            }
        } while(op != 7);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: no acabo de entender la pregunta, de todas maneras me da errores de compilación. dado que `reverse` devuelve una `Tlista` la cabecera seria `Tlista reverse(Tlista &lista)...` además dentro de la misma función `(lista->sgte)->sgte=list;` debes cambiar `list` por `lista`

Comment: Ya hice los cambios, queda algo así

Comment: Tlista reverse(Tlista &lista){//Aquí está el problema
 Tlista ptr = lista;
 
 if(lista->sgte!=0){
  ptr = reverse(lista->sgte);
  
  (lista->sgte)->sgte=lista;
  lista->sgte=0;
 }
 
 return ptr;
}

Comment: Lo que debo de hacer es mostrar invertida la lista, ósease. 12345 -> 54321

Comment: Puedes corregir el código editando tu primer mensaje. Quedará mas legible la pregunta.

Comment: Agrega por favor tu los de entrada y salida de tu consola

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te dejo algunos comentarios a tu código primero:

La palabra `reverse` es usada por las librerías de las STL para las funciones que hacen los recorridos inversos, así que sería mejor idea no usarla.

Por otro lado, no hay que hacer esto (al menos no es necesario):

```
Tlista t = new(struct nodo);
```

Se puede dejar así:

```
Tlista t = new(nodo);
```

Además, todas estas reservas de memoria hay que liberarlas antes de salir del programa.
Por último, si estás en C++ mejor usar las cabeceras propias `cstdlib` en lugar de `stdlib.h` (aunque ni siquiera hace falta esa librería en este ejercicio)

Y bueno, respecto a la función, parece que haces uso de recursividad para obtener la lista inversa, así que mi propuesta no creo que te sirva, pero ahí va. Simplemente hace uso de tu propia función `InsertFirst()` para construir esa lista inversa que luego se devuelve:

```
Tlista inversa(Tlista &lista)
{
    Tlista lista_inversa = NULL;
    Tlista raiz = lista;
    while (raiz!=NULL)
    {
        InsertFirst(lista_inversa,raiz->nro);    
        raiz = raiz->sgte;
    }
    return lista_inversa;
}
```